# Django ORM Syntax for 'LIKE' queries with respect to Datetime

Tags: python, django

I have this table which has column "date" in the format "2021-03-12 08:12:44.350176".
I want to compare a external date such as "2021-03-12 08:12:44"

I have tried this

```
new_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 12, 8, 12, 44, tzinfo=<UTC>)

obj = Test.objects.filter(date__contains=new_date).all()
```

But it doesn't work, it returns empty sets.
My goal is to fetch all the records against the new_date.

Is there a way to remove milliseconds or way to compare the two dates?

Comment: what do you exactly want? you want objects after date or before date?

Comment: for the same date, but my field stores the data with milliseconds, and I have a date without milliseconds, so basically its not getting compared

Comment: try this `YourModel.objects.filter(some_datetime__date=some_date)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to compare datetimes upto the second while *truncating* the milliseconds. You can do that (and similar) by using either [`Trunc` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) or one of it's subclasses. For truncating to the seconds you can use `TruncSecond` for your purpose:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models.functions import TruncSecond
from django.utils import timezone


new_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 12, 8, 12, 44, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

obj = Test.objects.annotate(
    trunc_date=TruncSecond(
        'date',
        tzinfo=timezone.utc
    )
).filter(trunc_date=new_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [[Django Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date):

> date
> For datetime fields, casts the value as date. Allows chaining additional field lookups. Takes a date value.

date means a `datetime.date` object.

so you can use `__date` for `datetime` fields.